# I have one good and one bad question (or is it plural "questions"?)

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

> - I have one good and one bad *question*
> - I have one good and one bad *questions*

I can invent rationales for both answers, which does not help.

I am tempted to prefer the first proposal, "I have one good and one bad *question*", especially if I replace question by, say, mouse. But I also prefer "Here *are* one good and one bad question(s?)" over "Here *is* ..". This is only getting more confusing.

Comment: "Here are one good and one bad questions" strikes me as decidedly ungrammatical. So does "I have one good and one bad questions".

Comment: I have two questions: one good and one bad. Any other use of **one** will be singular

Comment: This is derived from _I have one good question and I have one bad question_ by deleting the first _question_ and the second _I have_. _Question_ is singular in the original and doesn't change.

Comment: @John Lawler: Thanks for the clear explanation. Would you by chance also have a nice explanation for "Here are/is .." ?

Comment: That sentence is, as @RegDwigнt pointed out, ungrammatical. You're not doing conjunction reduction on whole clauses here, just a conjoined noun phrase _one good question and one bad question_, with the first _question_ deleted. Since conjoined count noun phrases are plural -- _Bill and Mike are coming_ but _*Bill and Mike is coming_ -- the verb has to be plural. But once again the undeleted noun does not become plural.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct

> I have one good and one bad question

Making two distinct sentences from the original, you'll get:

> - I have one good question.
> - I have one bad question.

Both sentences are correct, but if you use

> I have one good and one bad questions

and try to make two distinct sentences you'll get:

> - I have one good questions.
> - I have one bad questions.

both wrong.

Comment: Euclides, Welcome to the ELU site. Please use standard capitalization and punctuation in your answer, since we are a site about that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The first proposal is correct, use "*and*" as a conjunction there is syntactically a way of putting two different lexemes/phrases of the same category in the one spot.

So, the sentence, like Euclides wrote, is interpreted like this:

> I have (one good/one bad) question.

And either of the two partial phrases in the brackets can be chosen to modify 'question'. (I say partial, because they are only noun modifiers and the full phrase needs a head, which in this case, a "*Noun Phrase*" (NP), is the noun itself.)

This means that this is a shortening of two longer semantic ideas, namely:

> - I have one good question.
>
> *and*
>
> - I have one bad question.

This is why the plural of the noun is wrong. Although, as shown, there are semantically two questions, grammatically there is only one question.

As a result, the other sentence you've given beginning with *here* is:

> Here is one good and one bad question.